# why 'this' point to 'window' obj when using assignment operator in iife?

Tags: javascript, iife

I was wondering why the example will return 'global' not 'obj2'? And what's different between '(obj2.say = obj1.say)()' and '(obj2.say)()'?
Here is the code:

```js
var text = 'global';
var obj1 = { text: 'obj1', say: function () {console.log(this.text)}};
var obj2 = { text: 'obj2'};
(obj2.say = obj1.say)();
```

Comment: There is no IIFE here.

Comment: @FelixKling - Not in the traditional sense, but `(obj2.say = obj1.say)` is an expression that evaluates to be a function, and that function is immediately invoked... (But yes, you're right.)

Comment: I would expect it to return obj1. Interesting

Comment: Yup, @nnnnnn is right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *result* of an assignment is the value that was assigned. Example:

```
var foo, bar;
foo = (bar = 42);
console.log(foo); // 42
```

Hence when you do `(obj2.say = obj1.say)`, the result of the assignment, was returned by the grouping operator, is the *function object* in `obj1.say`.

The whole expression to be be equivalent to

```
var result = obj2.say = obj1.say;
result();
```

And when a function is called the "normal" way (`func()`), [`this` refers to the global object or is `undefined` in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196).

---

`(obj2.say)()` is quite special actually. The grouping operator alone does not *resolve* (internal) references to values. I.e. the result of `obj2.say` is, internally, a reference that describes the member access `say` on `obj2`. The grouping operator, `(...)` returns that reference unchanged, not resolving it to the actual function object. That's why `this` will correctly point to `obj2`. Omitting the grouping operator has the same effect.

This is actually [called out in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-grouping-operator):

> This algorithm does not apply [`GetValue`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-getvalue) to the result of evaluating *Expression*. The principal motivation for this is so that operators such as `delete` and `typeof` may be applied to parenthesized expressions.

Comment: `result = obj2.say = obj1.say` is the explanation I was struggling to give in my own (now discarded) answer. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of (obj2.say = obj1.say) is a plain Function object, while obj2.say() is a method call with obj2.

Answer (score -1):

`(obj2.say)()` will just call the `say` function from `obj2`.

`(obj2.say = obj1.say)()` will assign `obj1.say` to `obj2.say` and then call it.

I am not sure about the `this.text` - I'm hoping someone can help with that - even I am curious to find that out.