# What are the steps in Immediately Invoked Function Expressions for objects?

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to understand what is going "under the hood". Other questions dont explain the mechanics I am interested it. Please see code under.

I am looking for steps like this:

1. `(p.foo = o.foo)();` expresion
2. Value of `o.foo` is hold somewhere and is not yet related to p obj?
3. Value of `o.foo`get executed?
4. `p.foo` gets the value on `o.foo`?

is this right? if yes then need more info in step 2 on how, where and why...

```js
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;
var o = { a: 3, foo: foo };
var p = { a: 4 };

o.foo(); // 3
(p.foo = o.foo)(); // we get 2 and not 4”
```

Comment: When you want to get `4` instead of `2` then you need to do this: `o.foo.call(p);` or `(p.foo = o.foo.bind(p))()`  then `foo` is executed in the context of `p` and not in the context of `window` as `var a = 2;` is assigned to (in the last row)

Comment: It should be obvious from the grouping that the assignment happens before the function call

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45558692/1048572

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why 'this' point to 'window' obj when using assignment operator in iife?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558692/why-this-point-to-window-obj-when-using-assignment-operator-in-iife)

Comment: There are no steps explaining the mechanics in those other questions =((

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin What do you mean by "mechanics"? How the expression is parsed, or how it is evaluated? What exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special happening here.

This line

```
(p.foo = o.foo)();
```

is equivalent to executing below function in global scope(this refers to window) where value of a is 2 which gets printed.

```
    function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}
```

following assignment returns function definition

```
p.foo = o.foo
```

its not executing foo on p or o object. its just adding property foo on p object and assigning it that function.

Hence , you end up executing code in global scope

```
   (function () {
    console.log( this.a );
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

`p.foo = o.foo` is an expression. All expressions resolve to a value. In this case, it's the function `foo()`.

So basically, when you call this code, you not only *assign* a new value to `p.foo` (because it so happens that the expression contains the assignment operator `=`) -- you  also *get back* the global function `foo` as a result of *evaluating the expression*.

You then call the function inline in the `window` context, where `a` equals to 2.